# Improving misclassification for one class in a multi-class classification task

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, accuracy, multilabel-classification

Here I am trying to use 3 convolution layer neural network to classify a set of images (train data: (3249) , validation data: (487), test data: (326))

I have one class which is misclassified and I cannot understand what to do next. I have tried to reduce the value of dropout layer, but results got worst.

I know that the next solutions could be useful if I had bad classification for all classes :

- Get more data
- Try New model architecture, try something better.
- Decrease number of features (you may need to do this manually)
- Introduce regularization such as the L2 regularization
- Make your network shallower (less layers)
- Use less number of hidden units

What do you thing could be a good choice if I have only misclassifcation of one class?
Number of  total samples per class :

Black rot: 1180

Esca: 1383

healthy: 423

leaf blight: 1076

[image]

I had split the two datasets as follow:

```
x_train, _x, y_train, _y = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, stratify = y, random_state = 1)
x_valid,x_test, y_valid, y_test = train_test_split(_x,_y,test_size=0.4, stratify = _y, random_state = 1)
```

Comment: It would be good to get an idea of class distribution across the whole dataset, model architecture (and see a model variance / bias analysis [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html]) before making such a recommendation. If you could edit your post to at least include this information, that would be great.

Comment: Your dataset is quite small. Did you use stratified splits to get your train/val/test sets? Do you have enough samples in the class which was misslcassified?

Comment: yes I used 0.2 to test and 0.4 from testing dataset to train

Comment: I could not acces the link mentioned below

Comment: I noticed somthing that when I compile the model two times successively I got better results: it is normal? 0.959 (training), 0.952 (validation) and 0.969 (testing)

Comment: What do you mean by `compile the model two times successively`? Do you mean you trained it twice in succession?

Comment: yes I executed model.fit then I redo it again using the next code:  ' history_3conv = cnn3.fit_generator(train_data,steps_per_epoch = train_data.n // 98, ...) '

Comment: Probably would make more sense to just train for a larger number of epochs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that there are too many `Escas` in your dataset. If you look at the confusion matrix, the `Esca` column gets predicted (wrongly and correctly) much more that the others. This is clearly a symptom of a skewed data set.

Try augmenting your images to generate a larger 'super-dataset'. Then sample a 'sub-dataset' from that 'super-dataset', such that it has an equal distribution across all classes. Train on the 'sub-dataset'.

If you can't augment your data to have a better distribution across the 4 classes, here are some ideas:

1. Modify the loss function to more aggressively penalize `Black Rot`s classified as `Esca`s.
2. Split into two networks; the first differentiates between
   `Leaf Blight`-`Healthy`-`Black Rot/Esca`, and the second differentiates between
   `Black Rot`-`Esca`.

Comment: Means I need to modify the "categorical_crossentropy"  so to resolve the class imbalance problems?

Comment: Well, you have to essentially create a custom loss function. But you can probably base it off of `categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Thank you a lot !